# Is there a way to rollback an Android Studio update?

Tags: android, updates

As a student learning Android programming, the newest update to Android Studio 1.4 has been a total cluster****. There have been a number of new files added to the project you get from using all the defaults. Deleting any of these files, or deleting any of the values in some of these files, results in a slew of errors in the Android Manifest file. I would really like to avoid dealing with all this, so here's my question:

Is there a way to rollback an update in Android Studio 1.4?
I'm guessing the answer is no. A search of the web showed a few promising hits, but these were all for releases in the 0.* range. And developer.android.com is silent on the issue.

If the answer is no, am I screwed if I don't have an installer from before this update? Or should I just ignore the files for now and not delete any lines of code in these files I am not using. Just starting out in this, I understood quite clearly the files that USED to be generated by the default project settings. All these new files they just tossed in? I'm clueless (for now).

Comment: Welcome to SO. Shot in the dark, and I know it does not always work, but have you tried a restore point?

Comment: A restore point is an excellent idea. Unfortunately, I don't have a restore point recent enough to be of help. I guess that will teach me to create restore points much more frequently than I currently do ... and I'm kinda asking for my entire class. I'll suggest that to my classmates in case any of them were smarter than me. In the future, I also think I'll cancel out of any updates, create a restore point, then go ahead with the update ;).

Comment: I think you can always choose an "Empty Activity" project :)

Comment: Whoever downvoted this valid question is plain wrong. I have tried to get updates both from the stable channel and the dev channel but they are both annoying due to the very same issues in the question. So I am simply fed up by the conflicts of their updates and Gradle build mismatch.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can find some older versions of Android Studio here: https://developer.android.com/studio/archive

Comment: That worked, thanks! Had to drop back to the full build for 1.3.1 since the 1.4 betas and RCs did not actually have installers. Also had to update the SDK packages, but it seems that the most recent versions of the packages are still compatible with 1.3.1.

Comment: This website no longer provides downloads.

Comment: Is there another place (i.e. bit torrent) where the removed builds are avail?

Answer (score 0):

You actually have a couple of options :
Either to ***rollback***, or to ***manage different versions of Android Studio.***

1. To rollback to your previous Android Studio version, visit https://developer.android.com/studio/archive, agree to the terms, and access the archive at https://developer.android.com/studio/archive.html. From there, you can download versions starting from 2017, at my time of writing the archive began with Android Studio 2.3.2 released on May 11, 2017. Uninstall your unintended version and install your intended version.
2. If you prefer to keep your current version and install another Android Studio version separately, you can create an empty directory and install your intended alternative version there as another instance of Android Studio. The file name is studio64.exe inside the \bin directory, you can make a Desktop shortcut of it.

[*Here's a snapshot of two instances of Android Studios, Electric Eel & Chipmunk, operating on my single laptop, side-by-side.*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1OR8.jpg)

The second option setup allows you to work with distinct versions of Android Studio without conflicts.